# How to call different APIs using Curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl, response

I have a button when it is clicked it sends Post data to a php file and based on the method of the button, it will trigger that method using a switch statement. for instance:

```
$php_postdata->method ='clean';

switch($php_postdata->method){
case 'clean':
 $url = 'urlwithapi.com';
 $data = '{"name":"'. $php_postdata->name. '}';
 break;
}
$haders = 'blah blah blah';
$ch = curl_init();
 .....
 ......
  curl_setopt(); items
curl gets executed.
curl_close($ch);
 $json_response = json_encode($php_response);
//echo out the response
 echo($jsonresponse);
```

my question is, how do I re-run this script after the first pass, I want to add another method to the switch statement using the response from method of 'clean' and echo back that response.

any suggestions are welcomed.

thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking!

Comment: Have you tried a `foreach` loop like this: `foreach($php_postdata as $data) { ... [your code here] ...}`?

Comment: SkyLavi, the only problem is, I have to make one call to get data, then re-run the curl with a different api, but I want to re-use the switch(). better yet. I think I can pass in the switch statement to a function where the curl will be hosted at.

Comment: You should probably put your curl inside of a function that accepts your post data then you can pass in a multidimensional array of endpoints to loop over.

Comment: That is what I was thinking about doing. I'll keep you posted. Thanks